# "Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found" while building app in Bluemix

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud

I'm understanding Bluemix. I can deploy an app in it, but when I enter the URL I get this error. Why does this happen?

```
:Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /
```

This is my servlet class:

```
@WebServlet(description = "My First Servlet", urlPatterns = { "/FirstServlet" , "/FirstServlet.do"}, initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="id",value="1"),@WebInitParam(name="name",value="pankaj")})
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String HTML_START="<html><body>";
    public static final String HTML_END="</body></html>";
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FirstServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Date date = new Date();
        out.println(HTML_START + "<h2>Hi There!</h2><br/><h3>Date="+date +"</h3>"+HTML_END);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

and the jsp file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hi There!</h2>
<br>
<h3>Date=<%= new Date() %>
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

How can solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your .jsp filename? 
Enter index.jsp as the file name and then try again!